# 404 error with url ending with ICO

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am running on ubuntu 15.04, nginx 1.6.2

When i access my web app url e.g http://example.com/563sd177348ead0e8a028b45af/xxxico

I realised that whenever my url ends with "ico", nginx will throw a 404 error.

http://example.com/563sd177348ead0e8a028b45af/xxxxxx is accessible though

Can anyone advice?

Comment: can be related with wrapping static files extensions - jpg,gif,ico etc. Show us your `server {}` block

Comment: thanks @SergiiP have fixed it! u r right!